# Comparing an array's values e.g a with b with c with d?

Tags: php, twitter

How will I create a function to take an array of tweets from twitter using TwitterOAuth by Abraham Williams, to be able to compare the array of tweets e.g

Tweet A With Tweet B With Tweet C and so on?

```
require_once('Twitter/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('Twitter/Twitter_Config.php');

$userTimeline = $connection->get('statuses/user_ti');

function createAnArrayofTweetTimes($timeline)
{
    $tweetTimes = array();

    foreach ($timeline as $tweet) {
        $tweettext = strtolower($tweet->text);
        if (stristr($tweettext, '#edgarsclub')) {
            array_push($tweetTimes, $tweet->created_at);
            array_push($tweetTimes, 1);
            echo $tweet->created_at;
        }
    }
    return $tweetTimes;
}
```

I want to take this value which will be an array

```
 $tweetTimes = $createAnArrayofTweetTimes($usertimeline)
```

And compare each tweet with the next one using the succeeding function.

```
function tweetTime($x, $y)
{
    //THIS FUNCITON WILL COMPARE TWEETS WITH ONE ANOTHER
    //TAKE PRECEDING TWEET AND COMPARE WITH SUCCEEDING TWEET
    //IF LESS THEN 24 RETURN FALSE

    $currentTime = strtotime($currentTime);
    $tweetTime = strtotime($tweetTime);
    $timeInSeconds = $currentTime - $tweetTime;

    if ($timeInSeconds > 84600) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an incomplete line, and you need to define what you mean by "compare the array of tweets".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I have updated the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below a suggested approach:

```
function compareTweets($tweetTimes) {
    for ($i=0; i<count($tweetTimes)-1; $i++) {
        if (tweetTime($tweetTimes[$i], $tweetTimes[$i+1]) {
            //do what you want when the tweet time is more than 24h
        }
        else {
            //do what you want when the tweet time is less than 24h
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. If not please post again. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the downvotes... My code was wrong - I updated the name of the variable and replaced a "=" with a "+" inside the code. It should work now.... I hope... :O)